# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError How to define 'restaurant'

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

as the title says I'm getting an error code when I attempt render one of my website pages.

Here are the parts of the traceback that are pointing to my code:

```
  File "/vagrant/catalog/project.py", line 48, in newMenuItem
    return render_template('newMenuItem.html', restaurant_id=restaurant.id)

  File "/vagrant/catalog/templates/newMenuItem.html", line 9, in block "content"
    <form action="{{ url_for('newMenuItem', restaurant_id=restaurant.id) }}" method="POST">
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 397, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
UndefinedError: 'restaurant' is undefined
```

As you can see it is telling me that 'restaurant' is not defined, at first I thought perhaps I wasn't querying my database correctly so I double checked that section of my code and I can't find any problems.

Here is my python module and relevant html file:

```
### Create new menu item. ###
@app.route('/restaurant/<int:restaurant_id>/menu/new/',
            methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def newMenuItem(restaurant_id):
    restaurant = session.query(Restaurant).filter_by(id=restaurant_id).one()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newMenuItem = MenuItem(name=request.form['name'],
                               description=request.form['description'],
                               price=request.form['price'],
                               restaurant_id=restaurant.id)
        session.add(newMenuItem)
        session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('showMenu', restaurant_id=restaurant.id))
    else:
        return render_template('newMenuItem.html', restaurant_id=restaurant.id)
```

and here is the newMenuItem html file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="twelve columns">
  New Item.
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="six columns">
    <form action="{{ url_for('newMenuItem', restaurant_id=restaurant.id) }}" method="POST">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="six columns">
          <label for="Item Name">Item Name</label>
          <input class="u-full-width" placeholder="New Item" name="name" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="six columns">
          <label for="Item Name">Item Description</label>
          <input class="u-full-width" placeholder="Description" description="description" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="six columns">
          <label for="Item Name">Item Price</label>
          <input class="u-full-width" placeholder="Price" price="price" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="six columns">
          <input class="button" value="Create" type="submit">
          <a class="button" href="{{ url_for('showMenu', restaurant_id=restaurant.id) }}">Cancel</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I am having trouble understanding why this error is being thrown with this specific page, as I have used similar url_for code to create a new restaurant. The only thing I could think of that would be causing this issue is that my template cannot figure out the restaurant id where the new menu item should be created. I am unsure of how to read this error code as I do not know whether it is telling me that 'restaurant' as a variable is undefined, or that 'restaurant' is undefined in the sense that my code cannot call the correct id.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*There is no `restaurant` variable passed into the template context*, there is only `restaurant_id` in the context. Replace:

```
return render_template('newMenuItem.html', restaurant_id=restaurant.id)
```

with:

```
return render_template('newMenuItem.html', restaurant=restaurant)
```

Or, if you need only the restaurant ID in the template, leave the rendering part as is and access the id via `restaurant_id` instead of `restaurant.id`.

Comment: This was the solution. Thanks for the fast response! This is my first question on stackoverflow, it is telling me I must wait 8 minutes to mark the question as solved so I will do that in a few minutes,

Answer (score 0):

The variable restaurant has the wrong name!

```
<a class="button" href="{{ url_for('showMenu', restaurant_id=restaurant_id) }}">Cancel</a>
```